# Git hook to run tests for an application whenever there is an update

Tags: git

How do I configure the appropriate Git hook to run tests for my application using cypress. So let's say i already have the angular application setup in another repository and cypress also set up in another repository. I also have a script to run and build the angular application and use apache to run it and then cypress will do it's job. what i want to acheive now is that whenever i make a push to the angular repository, it will run the bash script which pulls the updates from the angular application, builds it and run cypress:run to run the e2e tests. is this feasible?

Comment: Do you host the angular repository yourself, or is it hosted with a third-party provider?

Comment: both projects are hosted on GitLab with different repositories. cypress one and then the angular one @JimRedmond

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting these repositories yourself, then the answer is a post-receive hook (which will run on the receiving system after a successful push).

If someone else is hosting these repositories, though, then a post-receive hook isn't currently an option. Instead, you can use a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) - which is *not* a Git hook - to notify a different system about the change. That system can then start the tests and/or builds, as appropriate.

Comment: so what if i want to go on this route how will it be acheived? 

If you're hosting these repositories yourself, then the answer is a post-receive hook (which will run on the receiving system after a successful push)